# change image hidden property every second

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, hidden

I have an image view and I want to change the hidden property every second. So, it should be visible for a second then it should disappear for a second and then it should appear for a second and so on.

I tried doing something like this -

```
for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
{
    sleep(1);
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        self.redImage.hidden=YES;             
    }
    else{
       self.redImage.hidden=NO;   
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It waits till all the 10 seconds are over and then it appears. Can someone please tell me what do. Thank you

Comment: NEVER sleep on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a repeating timer for this:

```
NSTimeInterval intervalCountDownTimer = 1;
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:intervalCountDownTimer target:self selector:@selector(hideOrShow:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

This will call a method that will update the hidden attribute on your image.  You will need to create an NSInteger property on the class called timerCount to stop it after 10 seconds.

```
- (void)hideOrShow:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    self.redImage.hidden = !self.redImage.hidden;

    self.timerCount += 1;
    if( self.timerCount >= 10 )
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

After 10 iterations, you can simply invalidate the timer, which will stop it from running again.